# Failed to connect before the deadline

Tags: sdk, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to run a hyperledger fabric network locally on my ubuntu .

Now I have the API server  running on docker  via postman iam trying to connect to the API server on docker and port is also mapped

I am able to issue certificate from the ca service running on my local machine but when I am trying to query anything there is err

Connection profile

```
    "name": "first-network-org1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "3000"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "peer1.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://192.168.19.135:7051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "192.168.19.135"
            }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://192.168.19.135:8051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "192.168.19.135"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "https://MYIP:7054",
            "caName": "ca-org1",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is error

```
019-08-31T03:22:19.109Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://192.168.19.135:7051
2019-08-31T03:22:19.111Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://192.168.19.135:7051
2019-08-31T03:22:22.120Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://192.168.19.135:8051
2019-08-31T03:22:22.120Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://192.168.19.135:8051
2019-08-31T03:22:22.121Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://192.168.19.135:8051
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://192.168.19.135:8051
    at Network._initializeInternalChannel (/middleware/api-server/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:112:12)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Failed to connect before the deadline 

"ssl-target-name-override": "192.168.19.135" >>> Should not be IP address
```

"ssl-target-name-override": {service_name}

Check below-updated config file

```
"name": "first-network-org1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "3000"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "peer1.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://192.168.19.135:7051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
            }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://192.168.19.135:8051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.example.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "https://MYIP:7054",
            "caName": "ca-org1",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i had the earlier the service name over here but it always tried to ping the grpcs://localhost:7051 not where the actual peer is running and i am making request inside the docker to my ubuntu machine

Comment: {
    "message": {
        "message": "Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://192.168.19.135:8051",
        "stack": "Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://192.168.19.135:8051\n    at Network._initializeInternalChannel (/middleware/api-server/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:112:12)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)"
    }
}

Comment: Try to run api server and hyperledger in docker swarm and replace all IP with local host in your connection profile

Comment: Thanks for the answer but now i am able to access the peers from the docker container .Just added -add-host flag to docker run command

Comment: That's why you should always brief your question as much as you can. If you would have left compose file or docker run commands would have easy to figered out. Moreover never use docker run while you are dealing with multiple services, use compose file with links or go for orcestration like swarm.